# TypeError when i click in checkbox

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i have one issue to solve but i'm don't have idea why this error appears to me [image: (error here)]

my code is below

```
const [selectedUsersList, setSelectedUsersList] = useState<number[]>([]);

  const handleSelectedUserCheckbox = (value: number) => {
    if (!selectedUsersList?.includes(value)) {
      setSelectedUsersList([...selectedUsersList, value]);
    } else {
      setSelectedUsersList(selectedUsersList?.filter((id) => id !== value));
    }
  };
```

and this is my checkbox

```
loadingUsers || userList?.getUsersForPush.length ? (
  (textToSearch?.length >= 3 && usersListSearch ? usersListSearch : userList 
    )?.getUsersForPush?.map((user) => (
     <Field
     as={Checkbox}
     key={user.id}
     name="userIds"
     value={user.id}
     label={user.name}
     title={user.name}
     id={`userIds-${user.id}`}
     className={styles.fieldsCheckbox}
     checked={selectedUsersList?.includes(
     Number(user.id)
    )}
      onChange={() =>handleSelectedUserCheckbox(Number(user.id))}/>
 ))
```

Comment: Can you reproduce it on stackblitz or something like that?

Comment: @Sagie in stackblitz or similiar, i can't reproduce the error, sorry

Comment: Well, lets then try to investigate it with some logs. Try to add `console.log` before line 149 of `value` and `selectedUsersList`.

As a side note: When you are setting state based on the previous state it is preferred to pass the `setState` a function. So in your case it will be something like this: `setSelectedUsersList((prevSelectedUsers) => [...prevSelectedUsers, value])`.
Check: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates